# How to print an empty date_time_string in BaseHTTPRequestHandler?

Tags: python-3.x, basehttpserver

I have built a tiny `httpd` using `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` in Python3. At the moment, it logs every HTTP GET request in `systemd` journal like this:

```
Oct 18 23:41:51 ubuntu httpd.py[19414]: 192.168.0.17 - - [18/Oct/2018 23:41:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I would like to avoid printing the timestamp printed by my `httpd`. Handler for HTTP GET requests is following:

```
def do_GET(self):
  self.send_response(200)
  self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
  self.date_time_string()
  self.end_headers()
```

Is it possible to disable printing the timestamp with `date_time_string()`? I tried with `self.date_time_string(None)`, `self.date_time_string(timestamp=None)`, but this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve desired log format, you need to write your own implementation of `log_message` method. You can go ahead and redefine `log_error` and `log_request` if you want to.